# How to count from a single table whilst performing multiple joins

Tags: mysql

I was asked the following question: 
Find the 3 vendors that supply our most famous products by number of units sold, not number of units ordered. Rank them first to third.

The database used is the online classicmodels db: http://mysqltutorial.org//tryit/

This is what I have done, I cannot seem to count the payments only and group by vendors. The count I get back is a product of all the joins.

```
SELECT p.productvendor FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN orderdetails AS od ON p.productcode = od.productcode
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.ordernumber = od.ordernumber
INNER JOIN customers AS c ON c.customernumber = o.customernumber
INNER JOIN payments AS py ON py.customernumber = c.customernumber
GROUP BY p.productvendor 
ORDER BY COUNT(p.productvendor) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: I see a relationship between customers and payments but don't see a way of matching payments to orders is there one?

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT....)

Comment: I think customernumber can be used to link the two. The ER diagram at this link should provide better clarity http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx

Comment: I think you are on the wrong track looking at at customers and payments - perhaps status (in orders) is a better way of identifying whats been sold , for example you probably wouldn't ship until payment has been made or is certain to be made,

Answer (score 0):

Try to break the problem into smaller queries and then try to optimize the joins.

select count(p.productvendor) as product_count, p.productvendor from (**JOINS**) group by p.productvendor

```
            -- this should give count by vendor.  you can use sum(orderdetails.qty) also in case you
```

So the problem is reduced to be in the **JOINS**

*JOINS* ( has to be a collection of individual product sales)